# iterate through a dictionary that has a list within lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out a way to match a value in a nested list in a dictionary. Let's say I have this structure;

```
dict2 = {'key1': [ 2, ['value1', 3], ['value2', 4] ], 'key2' : [1, ['value1', 2], ['value2', 5] ], 'key3' : [7, ['value1', 6], ['value2', 2], ['value3', 3] ] }
```

Now let's say for key1, I want iterate through the first value of the lists only to look for a data match. So if my data is "value2" and i want to look for it in key1, then I want it to skip the '2' and check the first object in the two lists which are; value1, value2 for a match and that's it.

Tried doing this but it gave a keyerror: 1;

```
if 'value1' in dict2[1][1:]:
    print 'true'
else:
    print 'false'
```

Is this possible to do? Is there another way to do match search? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using list.index() which will return the position of the value/object you're looking for.

Comment: The key error is that there is no "1" as a key. Dict cant be indexed! They need "keys"

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question is using a numeric index instead of the string 'key1'.  Here's a modified version that should work:

```
if 'value1' in {array[0] for array in dict2.get('key1', [])[1:]}:
    print 'true'
else:
    print 'false'
```

That looks at all of the elements after the first in the array associated with 'key1' in your dictionary, if it exists.

Comment: This iterates through all the keys, I only want it it to iterate through the list values of 'key1'. You can see my example of how I tried to do this (and failed) to get an idea of what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I see.  `'value1' in dict2.get('key1', [])[1:]` should work for that.

Comment: I get: ` >>> 'value1' in dict2.get('key1', [])[1:] False `

Comment: Yes, I see.  I've updated the response with a version that should work.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hey Bo, thanks. That worked great, do you know if there's any way for it to only iterate the first values ie. goes through value1, value2 (and skips the integers) etc. Rather than, value1, 3, value2, 4

Comment: The solution above actually does this.  It puts these two-element arrays into the `array` variable, and only looks at `array[0]`.

Comment: Hey Bo, you're right thanks. Sorry I didn't realize this at first, works great!

Answer (score 1):

If you're confident that the given nested dictionary always has this format, then we can do something like:

```
def find_value(nested_dict, value):
    for key, nested_list in nested_dict.items():  # If Python 2, use .iteritems() instead.
        for inner_list in nested_list[1:]:
            if value == inner_list[0]:
                return True
    return False

dict2 = {'key1': [ 2, ['value1', 3], ['value2', 4] ], 'key2' : [1, ['value1', 2], ['value2', 5] ], 'key3' : [7, ['value1', 6], ['value2', 2], ['value3', 3] ] }

print(find_value(dict2, 'value2'))  # True
print(find_value(dict2, 'value5'))  # False
```

Comment: This iterates through all the keys, I only want it it to iterate through the list values of 'key1'. You can see my example of how I tried to do this (and failed) to get an idea of what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if 'value1' in d['key1'][1]:
     print('Value 1 found')

if 'value2' in d['key1'][2]:
     print('Value 1 found')
```

Comment: This iterates through all the keys, I only want it it to iterate through the list values of 'key1'. You can see my example of how I tried to do this (and failed) to get an idea of what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this works. As I mentioned to Bo, do you know if there's any way for it to only iterate the first values ie. goes through value1, value2 (and skips the integers) etc. Rather than, value1, 3, value2, 4 to find the match?

Comment: You can do `if 'value1' == d['key1'][1][0]: print('Value 1 found')`

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Problem with this is that it will only check the first object in the first list [value1, 3] and then stop. It won't check the other list(s) such as [value2, 4]. So If I tried `if 'value2' == d['key1'][1][0]: print('Value 2 found')` it wouldn't work :( I think what I'm after may not be possible and I have to rethink this data structure for efficiency.

Comment: `values = [v[0] for v in d['key1'][1:]]` then you can do: `if 'value1' in values` or `if 'value2' in values`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only inside the lists you may do something like this:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for item in value:
        if isintance(item, list):
            if desired_value in item:
                return item # Here it is!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x,v in dict2.items():
   if x == "key1":
     for i, e in enumerate(v):
        try:
            if e[0] == 'value2':
               print "True"
            else: print "False"
        except:pass
```